# ¿Cómo puede mantener un formulario en un mensaje modal cuando la información de este ha sifo enviada, es decir que no se cierre?

Tags: php, html5

Estoy trabajando un formulario dentro de una ventana modal con PHP, HTML y algo de Javascript (muy poco de este último).

La idea es, que, una vez que el usuario presione el botón enviar, **se valide el formulario**.Es decir, que si contiene todos los datos y de manera correcta, se envíen. De lo contrario, se le avisa al usuario qué es lo que le falta llenar.

El problema es: esté correcto o no, una vez presionado el botón enviar, la ventana modal se cierra y no quiero que pase eso. **¿Cómo puedo hacerle para que la ventana modal se quede estática?** Siendo la única manera para que se cierre, que el usuario presione el botón salir (tache).

Imagen:

[image: Así es mi formulario]

Código:

```
<div class="formulario">
    <div class="bckform animated shake">
        <div class="cerrar">
            <a href="javascript:cerrar();"><img src="images/close.png" title="Cerrar"></a>
        </div>
        <h1>¡Déjanos un comentario!</h1><br/>
        <hr/>
        <form name="Comentarios" class="message" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="caja" placeholder="¿Cómo te llamas?" value="<?php if (!$enviado && isset($nombre)) echo $nombre ?>"> <br /><br/>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="caja" placeholder="Escribe tu correo electrónico" value="<?php if (!$enviado && isset($email)) echo $email ?>"><br/><br/>
            <textarea class="Space" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" placeholder="Cuéntanos algo! Dános tu opinión, sugerencia, queja y/o Felicitación." ><?php if (!$enviado && isset($mensaje)) echo $mensaje ?></textarea><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" class="boton" name="submit" value="¡Enviar Comentario!"><br/><br/><br/>

            <?php if(!empty($errores)): ?>

                <div class="alert error animated shake">
            <?php echo $errores; ?>
                </div>

            <?php  elseif($enviado): ?>
                <div class="alert success animated rubberBand">
                    <p>Muchas Gracias. Hemos recibido tu mensaje. Tu Opinión es muy Importante!</p>
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nota: Aunque quité la sentencia de `PHP_SELF`, se refresca la página.

Comment: Cuando dices que se cierra el modal, realmente te refieres a que la página se recarga, ¿no?

Comment: @Cesar ¿La validación del formulario se hace en el servidor (PHP) o en el cliente (JavaScript)?

Comment: En el servidor (PHP)

Comment: Alvaro Montoro, así es!! se recarga la página.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que necesitas es enviar el formulario en una petición ajax, lo puedes hacer con javascript o jquery, del lado del servidor utilizas las validaciones necesarias.

aqui te dejo un ejemplo:

```
// this is the id of the form
$("#idForm").submit(function(e) {

    var url = "path/to/your/script.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

saludos.